# using animatewithduration to move image view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, animatewithduration

I am trying to move an image multiple times. This is how i tried implementing it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.sattelite.center.x = 50
            self.sattelite.center.y = 100

            self.sattelite.center.x = 50
            self.sattelite.center.y = 50

            self.sattelite.center.x = 50
            self.sattelite.center.y = 300



        })

}
```

The animatewithduration method however only executes one of the movements. Is there any way to animate all three movements of the image view? Thanks.

Comment: which of the movements does it execute?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### you can easily chain animations ; start another at completion :

- **Here an illustration :**

  ```
  //1st animation
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
      delay: 0.0,
      options: .CurveEaseInOut | .AllowUserInteraction,
      animations: {
           //some code ex : view.layer.alpha = 0.0
      },
      completion: { finished in

          //second animation at completion
          UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0
              , delay: 0.0,
              , options: .CurveEaseInOut | .AllowUserInteraction,
              , animations: { () -> Void in

                 //some code ex : view.layer.alpha = 1.0

              }
              ,   completion: { finished in

                  //third animation at completion
                  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
                      delay: 0.0,
                      options: .CurveEaseInOut | .AllowUserInteraction,
                      animations: {
                           //some code ex : view.layer.alpha = 0.0
                      },
                      completion: { finished in
                      //FINISH : 3 animations!!!
                  })


          })
  })
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either chain the animations with completion or use a Key Frame animation

Answer (score 1):

Use the animation version which has completion:

```
class func animateWithDuration(_ duration: NSTimeInterval,
                    animations animations: () -> Void,
                    completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

Do the first animation only on `animations` and start the second in the `completion`. The third goes in the completion of the second.

So basically a chain of animations, where each starts when the previous finishes.